# Possible to export GtkWidget cairo_t drawing to vector image format (svg)?

Tags: c, svg, gtk3, cairo

I have found an application ([ufsm/ufsm-compose](https://github.com/jonasblixt/ufsm/tree/master/ufsm-compose)), which uses Cairo internally, to allow for vector drawing in the application GUI canvas.

I'd like to try to export the canvas drawing as a vector image - primarily SVG - with minimal changes to the program, however, I'm not sure whether it is possible.

This application uses `gtk_drawing_area_new` to instantiate a `GtkWidget` (`ufsmm_canvas_new` in `ufsm-compose/controller.c`), and then a `draw_cb` callback is made to run on `draw` event - similar to the approach here:

- https://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/basicdrawing/

Then, `draw_cb` "automagically" receives a reference to `cairo_t`, and uses that in calls to rendering functions, that use typical `cairo_rectangle` etc draw commands (see `ufsmm_canvas_render` in `ufsm-compose/render.c`).

However, I'm not really sure whether I can export these drawings somehow in a vector image (SVG). For instance, on this page:

- https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-SVG-Surfaces.html

... I can see that for SVG, one should call `cairo_svg_surface_create` - however, the `ufsm-compose` application does not use this command (in fact, there is no mention of the word "surface" anywhere in the `ufsm-compose` code -- which, otherwise, figures also in say `cairo_image_surface_create` (https://www.cairographics.org/tutorial/) which is used for bitmap images).

So, what are my options in exporting this drawing as an SVG (or other vector format)? Could I get away with instantiating a `cairo_svg_surface_create` upon export command, then somehow copying the application canvas' `cairo_t` to this SVG, and then finally save the SVG? If so - how exactly do I do this - can a full example be found on the Internet?

Comment: I never tried that but I would assume you need to create your new surface and also a context based on that surface. Then apply all your drawing function calls on that new context instead of the one passed to your function. Be aware that yout drawing function can be called frequently and you might need to take actions to prevent overwriting your file each time. I am not sure what would trigger writing the file with that approach.

Comment: Thanks @Gerhardh : "Then apply all your drawing function calls on that new context" - that was what I was afraid of/trying to avoid, at first look it feels like almost having to rewrite the render engine ...

Comment: Can't you just pass the new context to the functions you call withing your drawing_cb? Maybe it would even work to call them twice, once with your own context and once with the one from gtk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I get away with instantiating a cairo_svg_surface_create upon export command, then somehow copying the application canvas' cairo_t to this SVG, and then finally save the SVG? If so - how exactly do I do this - can a full example be found on the Internet?

Looking at the code of the `draw_cb`, [one finds](https://github.com/jonasblixt/ufsm/blob/053d97ba577bfcb2a9d3429925df679dd54d921f/ufsm-compose/controller.c#L4637-L4659):

```c
    struct ufsmm_canvas *priv =
                    g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "canvas private");

    gint width, height;
    GtkAllocation allocation;

    gtk_widget_get_allocation(widget, &allocation);

    width = allocation.width;
    height = allocation.height;

    priv->cr = cr;
    //priv->menu->cr = cr;
    priv->window_width = width;
    priv->window_height = height;

    ufsmm_canvas_render(priv, width, height);
    ufsmm_nav_render(priv, width, height);
    //menu_render(priv->menu, priv->theme, priv->selection, width, height);
    uc_status_render(priv, width, height);
```

So, apparently, the state of the application is kept in a `struct ufsmm_canvas`. When you have such a canvas, you have to decide on a size of your drawing and then there are just three functions to call to do the drawing.

So, to export the drawing, one could do (completely untested):

```c
void export_drawing(struct ufsmm_canvas *priv, int width, int height, const char* filename) {
    cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_svg_surface_create(filename, width, height);
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);

    priv->cr = cr;
    priv->window_width = width;
    priv->window_height = height;

    ufsmm_canvas_render(priv, width, height);
    ufsmm_nav_render(priv, width, height);
    //menu_render(priv->menu, priv->theme, priv->selection, width, height);
    uc_status_render(priv, width, height);

    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_destroy(surface);
}
```

---

EDIT: here is a tested version, along with a quick-n-dirty hack, so svg image always gets exported upon a save command:

```c
#include <cairo-svg.h>
...
void export_drawing(struct ufsmm_canvas *priv, int width, int height) {
    printf("export_drawing ufsm_out.svg ...\n");
    cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_svg_surface_create("ufsm_out.svg", width, height);
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);

    cairo_t *old_cr = priv->cr;
    priv->cr = cr;

    ufsmm_canvas_render(priv, width, height);

    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
    priv->cr = old_cr;
    printf("export_drawing DONE\n");
}

void canvas_save(void *context)
{
    struct ufsmm_canvas *priv = (struct ufsmm_canvas *) context;

    if (priv->model->filename == NULL) {
        canvas_save_as(context);
    } else {
        L_DEBUG("%s: writing to '%s'", __func__, priv->model->filename);
        remove_dangling_guard_refs(priv);
        ufsmm_model_write(priv->model->filename, priv->model);
        uc_rstatus_set(false);
    }
    export_drawing(priv, priv->window_width, priv->window_height);
}
```

Comment: Many, many thanks @UliSchlachter - that worked great, it was a life-saver! I have edited your answer and added the version that worked for me ... Thanks again!